# Is there any api for stop all hosts broadcasting to audience in my channel?

Tags: agora.io

Hi i building interactive live streaming app.

When i wish to leave channel i want to stop all hosts broadcasting to audience

also.Is there any api for that?

I used "leaveChannel" and "mute" apis but doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1. When the user leaves the channel, he can send a signal to the channel members through Agora RTM sdk. When the broadcasters receive this signal, they can call unpublish or mute to stop sending streams. Or they can call setClientRole to switch their role from broadcaster to audience.

RTM sdk quick start: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_android?platform=Android

2. When the user leaves the channel, he can call the "kicking-rule" RestFul API to specify who can send streams in the channel.

Kicking-rule API: https://docs.agora.io/en/rtc/restfulapi